# Blockchain Technology to enable autonomous interactions between the entities

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts

I have a hypothetical scenario in which I would need to land an Aircraft at the airport by factoring in the Airport Logistics to reach the Emergency Mobile Medical Unit while communicating with the Air Traffic Controller Station. Before landing, the Aircraft shall request and receive contingency flight plans from the Airspace Surveillance and Operations Service.

If I were to use Blockchain technology to enable autonomous interactions between the entities, what would your recommendation be in terms of the following

Network Type (public/private/protected/off-chain)

Smart Contract Agreements (challenges, metadata, and functions in terms of time-sensitive operations)

Consensus approaches within the network.

Information Security

Data Governance for Auditing and Monitoring purpose

|

Not looking for specifics necessarily, just broad strokes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the task in your case, it makes sense to use a decentralized platform only to exclude the possibility of a point of failure.

It should be a secure private network (Quorum+IPFS, Hyperledger Fabric, Corda). The nodes of the network will be airfields. If the number of nodes is more than 100, it will most likely require clustering. In principle, you can use Ethereum with PoA, but it is not stable enough, although a prototype can be built on it (+IPFS), especially if a subsequent transition to Quorum is expected.

The choice of consensus is determined by the threat model - it can be either a DFT consensus (such as Raft) or a BFT consensus if there is a threat, for example, malicious blocking of the dissemination of information over the network.

Given the importance of the posted information to the means of internal authentication of a decentralized network, I would add a trusted external PKI (such as Verisign) to sign the information distributed by the participants.

A similar infrastructure network was implemented by Gazprom-Aero to control the refueling of aircraft - https://www.gazprom-neft.com/press-center/news/gazprom_neft_aircraft_blockchain_platform_enables_instant_refuelling_payment/